# Reading Text File from Subdirectory

Tags: python, text, import, subdirectory

In my Python code, I have a text file in a sub-directory of my original python program that I would like to read. I am aware of the os.chdir() function, and it does work to do change the directory to where the file is before I read the file. However, I want this code to work on any machine no matter the directory, so is there a simple way to notate a changepath to a sub-directory so that it would work on any computer?

Thank you

```
-root folder
---run.py
---otherstuff
---lib folder
------otherlib folder
---------textfile.txt
```

Comment: What does your directory tree look like, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay I edited the original post, sorry I tried to make that make sense @grooveplex

Comment: you can read it using a relative path open("lib folder/otherlib folder/textfile.txt")

Comment: Thank you @Atirag that's what I was looking for! :)